# Insert an option from drop list to database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this drop list for example:

```
<p>Your Age:</p>
<select>
    <option value="1">0 - 13</option>
    <option value="2">13+</option>
    <option value="3">18+</option>
</select>
```

**WHAT I'M DOING NOW** is to take the value (1, 2, 3..) and insert it to the `users` table in the column `age`, how do I know which value belongs to age? I have a table `ages` with id and the age.

I'm not sure this way necessary, it's too much complicated and not effectively I think.

The other option is to take a string with the age and just put it in the column `age`, but this way is less dynamically and in what way I can check if the string is one from the ages?

What do you say?
Thank you.

Comment: `if($value == 1) $age = '0-13' elsei if ...` Like this ?

Answer (score 2):

You can either set the value of the option to match the value between the option tag when you generate the select field or you can have a look up array when you submit it - something like

```
$ageMap = array(
    "1" => "0 - 13",
    "2" => "13+",
    "3" => "18+"
);

// get the value using the posted value from your select field
$ageMap[$_POST["YourAge"]];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to give your select a `name` attribute, and then you can retrieve if from the $_POST variable in PHP, e.g.

```
<form action="your_php_page.php" method="post">
    <select name="age">
        ... 
   </select>
</form>
```

Then in PHP use:

$_POST['age']

Answer (score 0):

you need to give select box "name" attribute by which you can take values of select box from name attribute.

```
<select name="ages">
<option value="1">0 - 13</option>
<option value="2">13+</option>
<option value="3">18+</option>
```

When you click on submit ,in code just write

```
$age = $_POST['ages'];
```

You will get value of selected age from select box.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can create a attribute in the table with `enum(1,2,3)` and afterwards you can send value of 1, 2 or 3 to the table.

Advantages: You **don´t need** to save the ages in database just (1, 2, 3), You **don´t need** to save a extra table for ages, which is also a way (Creating a table of three ages and then relating one row in age column).

Disadvantag: Extra code (Maybe), depeding on how often you call it and how object-oriented you application is.

You can just check what ages is with a `if & else` and save it a global variable.

Comment: This is highly discouraged, because if you edit your code, the values in the database don't match. Normalize the ages in a different table.

Comment: What you mean by editing the code? If you change the values from (1,2,3) to (4,5,6) then none of given answers above will work ...

Comment: The best option is to store the ages in a different table, like `age(age_id, value)` and fill the select with the values from this table. When you pick an age, it corresponds to the value in the age table. This way, your code and database won't get out of sync.